# Firebase user/user roles database structures

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a web application with Firebase as the backend.
My application has a lot of moving parts. When a user creates an account, they register a company whose details I store in Firestore. The admin can then add multiple centers to the company. The account creator becomes the super admin of this company. They can also add admins to the company.

The company has centers under it. Each of these centers can have multiple admins as well, added by the super admin. I am now stuck on how to add these user roles to Firestore in a way that I can reference them in the application.

For now I have:

1. users collection (information about the user like name, email etc.)
2. roles collection (role id and role name)
3. centers collection (center information like location, address etc.)
4. company collection (company name, location etc.)
5. user_roles collection (user id, role id)

I am stuck on how to move forward with this so I can query the database and get a user, what center they are admin for and grant them access to that center's data.

Any assistance will be much appreciated. I am still working on the back-end so there's no code just yet.

Thanks,

Comment: What precisely are you stuck on? As in: what specific step in this whole use-case is not working? You'll find that we can be most helpful if you show the [minimal code that you got working for this use-case, and then in there indicate where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am stuck on creating a structure that links up all these collections. So that a user can be connected to a center or company and have the role also attached to that user data. I dont have any code yet because I am still working on the backend.